# Using jQuery UI Slider value in mySQL

Tags: mysql, jquery-ui, slider

I am using the jQuery UI Slider - http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/

When a certain value has been given by the user, I want to use that value in a new mySQL query and then reload the page with the new mySQL data. Anybody have an idea on how to do this? Can i make a mySQL query from javascript?

Below is the javascript that activates the slider.

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#slider" ).slider({
            value:100,
            animate:true,
            min: 0,
            max: 500,
            step: 100,
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.value );
                var value = $( "#slider" ).slider( "option", "value" );
            }
        });
        $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider" ).slider( "value" ) );
    });
</script>
```

Best, Slynge

Answer (score 2):

use the 'stop' event of the slider and make an ajax call to a .php script. In that script, handle the database transaction. Reload the page again with JavaScript.

EDIT

If you need the query on reload, you can, in the php script store the query in a S_SESSION variable and do a redirect to the original page. Read the query (if exists) from the $_SESSION and unset it.

Comment: Thanks. But how do I pass the slider value to the .php script?

Comment: You know how to get the slider value. Then use the jquery $.ajax function to call the .php script. Please read the documentation, do a little experimentation, and if you still have questions, do not hesitate to ask them. I could write the total solution for you, but you will learn more from first trying to do it yourself. Have fun and do not hesitate to ask more when needed.

Comment: Okay I will try experimenting.

Comment: I solved it in a different way. Passed the value through the URL to php and then make the SQL query in the same script. Thanks.